# How can I get the best seller by product group using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to retrieve the name, product type and sum of the seller with the highest sales in each product type using linq and return the list to a view.

```
{  
    public ActionResult Query2()
    {
        // this part gets me everything into one model type 
        List<QueryViewModel> result = db.SaleProducts
            .GroupBy(prod => prod.Type)
            .SelectMany(sale => sale.Select(
                row => new QueryViewModel
                {
                    Seller = row.Sale.User.Name,
                    ProductType = row.Type,
                    Sales = (double)sale.Where(x => x.Sale.UserId == row.Sale.UserId && x.Type.Equals(row.Type)).Sum(price => price.Price)
                }
            )).Distinct().ToList<QueryViewModel>();

        // this gives me the best per product type but i cant get the seller name 
        List<QueryViewModel> filter = (from res in result
                                       group res by res.ProductType into prodGroup
                                       select new QueryViewModel
                                       {
                                           ProductType = prodGroup.Key,
                                           Sales = prodGroup.Max(x => x.Sales)
                                       }).ToList<QueryViewModel>();

        // this is really just to get the seller name at this point 
        List<QueryViewModel> something = (from res in result
                                          join f in filter on res.Sales equals f.Sales
                                          select new QueryViewModel
                                          {
                                              Seller = res.Seller,
                                              ProductType = res.ProductType,
                                              Sales = res.Sales
                                          }).ToList<QueryViewModel>();

        return View(something);
    }
}
```

It should return a list of QueryViewModel(name, product type, total sales).

It does return that, but this seems horribly messy and I'm not understanding LINQ enough to clear this up.

Is there a better cleaner way to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first grouping should be by type and Seller.

Something like this should get you going:

```cs
Quote_Masters.GroupBy(qm => new { qm.OrderTypeId, qm.SalesRepEmployeeId })
    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key.SalesRepEmployeeId, x.Key.OrderTypeId, Total = x.Sum(qm => qm.Total_Price) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Total).GroupBy(x => x.OrderTypeId).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
```

Just change out your appropriate tables and fields.

---

Edit: Your select to QueryViewModel would be the new {Name = x.Key.SalesRepEmployeeId, x.Key.OrderTypeId, Total = x.Sum(qm => qm.Total_Price)}

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for marking this as the answer!